# Randomize setInterval ( How to rewrite same random after random interval)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know how to achieve:
generate a random number after a random number of time. And reuse it.

```
function doSomething(){
     // ... do something.....
}

var rand = 300; // initial rand time

i = setinterval(function(){

     doSomething();
     rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(3000-500))+500; // generate new time (between 3sec and 500"s)

}, rand);
```

And do it repeatedly.

So far I was able to generate a random interval, but it last the same until the page was refreshed (generating than a different time- interval).

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a reusable version that can be cleared. Open-sourced [as an NPM package](https://github.com/jabacchetta/set-random-interval) with IntelliSense enabled.

**Utility Function**

```
const setRandomInterval = (intervalFunction, minDelay, maxDelay) => {
  let timeout;

  const runInterval = () => {
    const timeoutFunction = () => {
      intervalFunction();
      runInterval();
    };

    const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDelay - minDelay + 1)) + minDelay;

    timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, delay);
  };

  runInterval();

  return {
    clear() { clearTimeout(timeout) },
  };
};
```

**Usage**

```
const interval = setRandomInterval(() => console.log('Hello World!'), 1000, 5000);

// // Clear when needed.
// interval.clear();
```

Comment: clean & simple solution

Answer (score 114):

Here is a really clean and clear way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/9GyyA/

```
function doSomething() {}

(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
            doSomething();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
```

**EDIT:**

Explanation:
loop only exists within the immediately invoked function context, so it can recursively call itself.

Comment: Nice solution, but it requires some change if you want to be able to remove "interval" in a while.

Comment: @toprightgamedev if you want to stop looping, simply place an if statement around the setTimeout with the logic you need.

Comment: Sorry to dig up this answer so many year after but I have a question : won't you have a stack of execution context that keep increasing without end with this solution ?

Comment: I found a nice explanation on why it does not create a stack of execution context : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506904/1951430

Comment: @jobou it does stack execution contexts. You're right.

Comment: what is the purpose of `(3000 - 500)) +  500`? is this supposed to make it more random?

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work - use `setTimeout()` instead so you can set a new random value each time:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert("doing something");
}

function init() {
    var myFunction = function() {
        doSomething();
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500; // generate new time (between 3sec and 500"s)
        setTimeout(myFunction, rand);
    }
    myFunction();
}

$(function() {
    init();
});
```

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BrokenGlass/XKA2s/).

Comment: @roXon: Yes - that way you can update the random interval each time

Comment: That's jQuery at the end, not plain Javascript.

Comment: How can you pass arguments with this method?

Answer (score 3):

Just setup interval each time you rand (and clear it first)

```
function doSomething(){
     // ... do something.....
}

var i;
var rand = 300;

function randomize() {
    doSomething();
    rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(3000-500))+500; 
    clearInterval(i);
    i = setInterval('randomize();', rand);
}

i = setInterval('randomize();', rand);
```

or try using setTimeout (and setting again after randing)

Comment: On a side note it should be `setInterval(randomize, rand);`

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing my hat in the ring

```
    var keepLooping = true;
    (function ontimeout(){
        if(keepLooping){
            doTheAction();
            setTimeout(ontimeout, Math.random() * 100);
        }
    })();
```

depends if you want to put `doTheAction()` inside the `setTimeout` callback or not. I think it's fine to put it before/outside. If you want the initial delay, then put it inside, if not, put it outside for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
function setRandomInterval(intervalFunction, minDelay, maxDelay) {
  let outerFunction = () => {
    let delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDelay - minDelay + 1)) + minDelay;
    let timeout = setTimeout(outerFunction, delay)
    intervalFunction(timeout)
  }
  outerFunction()
}
```

Usage:

```
let start = performance.now()
let i = 1
setRandomInterval((timeout) => {
  let end = performance.now()
  console.log("Run count", i)
  console.log("Random time elapsed", (end - start) / 1000)
  start = end
  i++
  if (i > 5) {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }
}, 500, 5000)
```