# How to play a sound at random time in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this sound:

```
a = new Audio('audio.mp3');
```

and when I want to play it I use `a.play()`
How can I play this at random times?

Comment: look at setTimeout() and Math.random()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setInterval** and **Math.random()** are what you are looking for.

```
a = new Audio('audio.mp3');
window.setInterval(function () {
    a.play();
}, Math.random() * 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500; // A random value between 3 and 500 seconds

    setTimeout(function() {
            a.play(); // Play the audio
            loop(); // Call the loop function again
    }, rand);
}());
```

Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962658/randomize-setinterval-how-to-rewrite-same-random-after-random-interval) question.